# Lazy Loading in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Can you please tell me how to correctly implement lazy loading with the use of trigerr in nuxt 3 that queries would occur only when a certain tab of the table is selected? When changing the tab url does not change, the idea is a bit like this:
Page loads -> Registers a component but no request is made.
User clicks on tab -> Triggers first request + sets flag to active. [image]
here is the component code

```
<template>
  <div class="container block-margin">
    <h3 class="text-orange">
      {{ $t("account.overview.welcome") }}
    </h3>
    <h3 v-if="fullCustomerName">
      {{ fullCustomerName }}
    </h3>

    <p>
      {{ $t("account.overview.description") }}
    </p>
    <AccountContent
      v-if="customerProfileValue"
      @updateHasUnsavedData="updateHasUnsavedData"
      :customer-profile="customerProfileValue"
      :customer-settings="customerSettings"
      :enabled-country-list="enabledCountryList"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useCustomerStore } from "~/store/customer";
import { AddressType } from "~/types";
import type { Country, CustomerSettings, SitemapProcessStep } from "~/types";

const { t } = useI18n();
const { processPageSeo } = useCms();

const { getCustomerProfile, getCustomerAddressList } = useCustomer();
const { customerProfile: customerProfileValue } = storeToRefs(
  useCustomerStore()
);

definePageMeta({ middleware: "auth" });

const fullCustomerName = computed(() => {
  if (!customerProfileValue.value) {
    return "";
  }

  const firstName =
    customerProfileValue.value.profile?.am_profile_person_firstname || "";
  const lastName =
    customerProfileValue.value.profile?.am_profile_person_surname || "";

  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
});

const customerSettings = ref<CustomerSettings | undefined>(undefined);
const { getCustomerSettings } = useCustomer();

const { getEnabledCountryList } = useLocale();
const enabledCountryList = ref<Country[]>([]);

const hasUnsavedData: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);

const updateHasUnsavedData = (value: boolean) => {
  hasUnsavedData.value = value;
};

const fetchData = async () => {
  const settings = {
    skipSteps: ["handlePageStatus" as SitemapProcessStep],
  };

  await processPageSeo("Account overview Page", settings);

  if (customerProfileValue.value) {
    const [enabledCountryListResponse, customerSettingsResponse] = await Promise.all([
      getEnabledCountryList(),
      getCustomerSettings(),
    ]);

    let { data: customerSettingsData }: any = customerSettingsResponse;
    enabledCountryList.value = enabledCountryListResponse.data.value.data;

    customerSettings.value = {
      send_info: customerSettingsData?.value?.data?.send_info,
      vat_payer: customerSettingsData?.value?.data.vat_payer,
      email: customerSettingsData?.value?.data?.account?.am_account_mail,
      id_country: customerSettingsData?.value?.data?.id_country,
    } as CustomerSettings;
  }

  await Promise.all([
    getCustomerProfile(),
    getCustomerAddressList(AddressType.BILLING_ADDRESS),
    getCustomerAddressList(AddressType.SHIPPING_ADDRESS),
  ]);
};

process.server ? await fetchData() : fetchData();

onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
  if (
    hasUnsavedData.value &&
    !confirm(t("account.overview.confirmLeavingWithoutSaving"))
  ) {
    return next(false);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
</script>
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: black;
}
h3.text-orange {
  color: #f18a00;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```

I've tried other approaches, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: I do not see any code for the tabs themselves so kindly update your question with the tab component code. Also, I urge you to look at try catch blocks instead of promises and to have another look at the Vue documentation on how to properly handle authentication.